# How to select a value from a DropDownList in a Word Macro using VBA?

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word

I am creating a macro using both vbscript and vba, this macro is being called by the script code and works well but when I try to select a value outside the macro itself, I keep getting an error about the way im trying to set the value.

I have named the dropdownlist as "Result" and when I try to set the value it does not work, I also tried with the default name "DropDownList" , but none of those options seems to work, maybe i am missing object references.

I already declared the objects that I need

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set activeDoc= objWord.ActiveDocument

activeDoc.FormFields("Result").DropDown.Value = 2
```

The error i am getting right now is that "The Requested memeber of the coleection does not exist."

The only solution I can come up with is to set the value when I'm creating the dropdown in the macro:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(Row: = 4, Column: = 4).Select
Set objCC =
    Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropDownList)
With objCC
    .Title = "Result"
    .Tag = "Result"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add("Passed", "Passed").Select
End with
```

Comment: `FormField` and `ContentControl` are not the same thing - these are different kinds of dropdown lists. Which kind do you actually plan to use / which kind is in the document you're addressing?

Comment: @CindyMeister it is a ContentControl but I got confused, that's why I used that

Comment: So it's OK, now? You know how to approach it in your code?

Comment: @CindyMeister I tried this : `Set objCc = activeDoc.ContentControls.Item(3) If objCc.Title = "Result" Then Set objLe1 = objCc.DropdownListEntries.Item(2) End if ` but it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: I don't understand what "tried this:" is supposed to be, but if you're trying to show me code, use the [edit] link below the question to add information.

Answer (score 0):

I got everything messed up, but in the end I realized what was my mistake. I wasn't using the tag so the Item was loose, I had to use the index of the correct content control

```
Set objCc = activeDoc.ContentControls.Item(5)
Set objLe1 = objCc.DropdownListEntries.Item(1)
objLe1.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your part of code, I have so much trouble to find how to do this !

I add just :

```
With ThisDocument.tables(blabla).Cell(x,y)
        Set objCc = .Range.ContentControls.Item(1)
        Set objLe1 = objCc.DropdownListEntries.Item(2)
        objLe1.Select
End With
```

And it works perfectly within my project ! Ty again, see you !